# Encountered two children with the same key, `18`. Keys should be unique

Tags: react-native

const findProduct = async (text) => {
// Build formData object.

```
console.log(name);
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('FindProduct', text);

const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.144/api/Search.php', {
method: "POST",
body: formData,
});

const data = await response.json();

setProduct(data);

if(data&&data.length>0){
  setId(data[0].id)
  setName(data[0].prodname)
  setCategory(data[0].category)
  setPrice(data[0].price)
  setQty(data[0].qty)
  setPic(data[0].pic)

  cartarray.push(data)
  
  
  
}
  setShoppingBag(cartarray);
}
```

const saveData = async(shoppingBag) => {

```
console.log('2nd cart:>>', shoppingBag)

try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(shoppingBag)).then(() =>{
      alert('Saved successfully.');console.log('saved cart');
    });
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

};

the first function if the bar code is recognized returns all his infos and then save in shoppingbag

Comment: This error usually comes when you are trying to map the objects with same key. Please share the code if you are using any map function or flatlist etc?

Comment: Okay can i share Project link with u?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a use case to reproduce this issue. I am trying to rendering MUI Table. So if you see I have key=fomrDataId assigned multiple times. To resolve this error you should have unique key values for TableCell.

There is one more possibility where this error can occur when you have duplicate values in formDataId as I have assigned formDataId as row key for TableRow key={row.formDataId}

[image]